# How can I use Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

I have tried to insert a simple message on firebase database using firebase documentation and firebase tool both but that is not updating.

I have also add picture of my firebase console after launching app.

Please help me to find bug!!!

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");
        myRef.setValue("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

**Gradle App**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}


android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.firebase_realtimedata001"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.2'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.4.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

**Console Image**

[image]

Comment: Make sure you have configured read and write rules in Realtime Database console

Comment: What is the location of your database, US central? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working perfectly fine. `Hello, World!` message is added to database when I click add button

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate ( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView ( R.layout.activity_main );
        Button addMessage = findViewById ( R.id.button );
        addMessage.setOnClickListener ( v -> addMessage () );
    }

    public void addMessage () {
        DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance ().getReference ( "message" );
        myRef.setValue ( "Hello, World!" ).addOnCompleteListener ( new OnCompleteListener<Void> () {
            @Override
            public void onComplete ( @NonNull Task<Void> task ) {
                Log.d ( "INFORMATION", "Added" );
            }
        } );
    }
}
```

After clicking addMessage button Realtime Database shows the message as follows

[image: Realtime Database Data]

Make sure you are having rules as shown below

[image: Realtime Database Rules]

Comment: @niranjan1997 - I tried same but problem is same.

Comment: @AlexMamo  - I choose singapur location for database